# Crash of VMWare Workstation when generating EER Diagram

Tags: mysql-workbench, vmware

I'm facing an issue when I'm generating an EER diagram with MySQL Workbench 8.0

I'm using MySQL Workbench on a local Windows 10 virtual machine. My VM is running with VMWare Workstation 12.5.0.

I select some tables, a stored procedure and generate the diagram. In the progress dialog, I can see the Reverse Engineering is successful. When it comes to place Objects on Diagram, the **virtual machine** crashes and shows this message :

> VMware Workstation unrecoverable error: (svga)
>
> Exception 0xc0000005 (access violation) has occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to prevent this crash.

In MySQL Workbench, go to *Edit > Preferences...*

Go to the *Modeling* section and tick "Force use of software based rendering for EER diagrams"

Restart MySQL Workbench.